# Bootstrap jQuery Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I've found an awesome open source calendar at http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/index-bs3.html

I'm trying to load this project as described [link removed]

As in the demo, there is a dynamic list on the side of the calendar that **does** update with the events as you scroll through. How ever unlike the demo, my events are not getting listed in the calendar view. They don't show up on the calendar! :(

I did add a couple extra json data options, but the required ones weren't changed. Here's an example of my json data:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "result": [{
    "id": "########",
    "title": "Event NAme",
    "start_time": "2014-08-23T18:30:00-0500",
    "start": "1408836600",
    "end_time": "",
    "end": "0",
    "class": "event-info",
    "url": "http://..."
  }]
}
```

I don't think it's a bug, but not sure why it's not working as expected.

Their code:

```
onAfterEventsLoad: function(events) {
        if(!events) {
            return;
        }
        var list = $('#eventlist');
        list.html('');

        $.each(events, function(key, val) {
            $(document.createElement('li'))
                .html('<a href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a>')
                .appendTo(list);
        });
    },
```

My code:

```
'onAfterEventsLoad': function(events) {
            if(!events) {
                return;
            }
            var list = $('#eventlist');
                list.html('');

            $.each(events, function(key, val) {
                var d = new Date(val.start_time),
                date = weekday[d.getDay()] + ", " + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + ", " + d.getYear();
                $(document.createElement('li'))
                    .html('<a title="' + date + '" href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a><br/><small>' + jQuery.timeago(d) + '</small>')
                    .appendTo(list);
            });
        },
```

Comment: Looking at the site in chrome - the dynamic list is updating ok, I can see one event when I look at the Year view. The problem must be in the adding of events - how are you adding them? Post some more code pls

Comment: I vote +1 just for your great found of http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/index-bs3.html! Enjoy!

Comment: I've added the `onAfterEventsLoad` functions @Starscream1984

Comment: Your events load from here? `https://www.serverbin.net/apps/event-strap/?id=ChildrensMuseumLakeCharles`

Comment: Correct. that's the current event url

Comment: There was a problem. Events without `end` parameter was not displayed. In the latest git source it is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are trying to load events from is simply returning `{"success":1}` and not any events for the `onAfterEventsLoad` handler to iterate through.

This is the cause of your problem, the calendar code is all working fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Right, but when you go to the month of August, there is an event..which does show in the dynamic `#eventlist` list. So the code is going through the `onAfterEventsLoad` function at that time

Comment: From the documentation:

If you have an error you can return

    `{
    "success": 0,
    "error": "error message here"
    }`

Comment: Yes, when you view August the event is returned, but it is not if you are not viewing August or the whole year - it will not show the event if you are viewing any other month

Comment: Yes, but as in the demo, the event in August should appear in the calendar on the day of the event as well! It does not.

Comment: Marked as correct because you had me checking my event url... I wasn't supplying an "end" time, which apparently is why it was not autoloading to the calendar!

Comment: Ah, I had to abandon investigation due to real work, but glad you got it sorted!